# Procesos con exec, fork y wait en c

Tags: c

Este ejercicio tiene por finalidad crear 2 procesos hijos:

- 1º hijo abra la calculadora de linux.
- 2º hijo abra N ficheros que le pasamos por linea de argumentos.

El problema es que no me crea N ficheros y los abre; sólo me abre la calculadora.

También me gustaría si alguien puede explicarme así por encima la familia `exec`,ya que ando un tanto liado con lo que realizan y que hacen en sí.

Código:

```
/*
Propósito: Implemente un programa donde se creen dos hijos. Uno de ellos que abra la calculadora de su
distribución de Linux (busque como se llama ese ejecutable) y el otro que abra un editor de textos
con N ficheros pasados como argumentos (recuerde hacer que el padre espere a los hijos). Use para
ello la familia de funciones exec(). EJEMPLO DE INVOCACION:
    ./miPrograma gnome-calculator gedit fichero1.txt fichero2.txt ficheroN.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Algoritmo: El programa va a pedir por linea de argumentos 2 hijos, uno abre la calculadora y otro un editor de textos con N ficheros.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void calculadora(char *f){
    if(execlp(f,f,(char*)NULL)<0){
        perror("Exec");
        printf("Errno value:%i\n",errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
void ficheros(char *f[]){
    if(execvp(f[0],f)<0){
        perror("Exec");
        printf("Errno value:%i\n",errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int status,n;
    pid_t pid,pidd;
    printf("Introduce una cantidad de ficheros: \n");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    if(argc!=3+n){
        printf("Error en los argumentos\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        pid=fork();
        if(pid==0){//Proceso hijo
            if(i==0){
                printf("Soy el 1º hijo, con PID %i y voy a abrir la calculadora\n",getpid());
                calculadora(argv[1]);
            }
            else{
                printf("Soy el 2º hijo, con PID %i y voy a abrir n ficheros\n",getpid());
                ficheros(argv+2);
            }
        }
        else if(pid>0){//Proceso padre
            pidd=wait(&status);
            if(WIFEXITED(status)){
                printf("Hijo %i ha sido esperado y su status es %i\n",pidd,WEXITSTATUS(status));
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)){
                printf("Hijo %i ha muerto y su status es %i\n",pidd,WTERMSIG(status));
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else if(WIFSTOPPED(status)){
                printf("Hijo %i ha sufrido un error y su status es %i\n",pidd,WSTOPSIG(status));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else if(pid<0){//Proceso error
            printf("Error al crear el proceso. Errno: %i\n",errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: con respecto al bloque de código que comienza con: ʻif (execlp (f, f, (char *) NULL) <0) `Las funciones ʻexec *` solo regresan si fallaron, por lo que el bloque de código debería ser: ʻexeclp (f, f, (char *) NULL)

        perror ("Error de ejecución");
        printf ("Valor de Errno:% i \ n", errno);
        salir (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

Comment: OT: con respecto a: `printf (" Error en los argumentos \ n ");` Los mensajes de error deben enviarse a `stderr`, no a `stdout`. Sugerir: `fprintf (stderr," Error en los argumentos \ n ");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonito problema. Me tome la libertad de reordenar el código; hace lo que se pide, pero no exactamente de la misma manera. Creo que ya entiendes como funciona el `fork`, pero te has quedado trancado en como llamarlos.

El código reordenado es lineal, no iterativo. Así queda más claro en que parte estamos.

Pongo la explicación como comentario del fuente, para no perdernos. Anoto con F0, F1 y F2 el proceso padre y los hijos.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int status, n;
    pid_t pid, pidd;
    int hijos = 0;
    printf("Introduce una cantidad de ficheros: \n");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    if (argc != 3 + n) {
        printf("Error en los argumentos\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // F0: Este es el primer fork
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // F1: Proceso hijo sigue por aquí
        printf("Soy el 1º hijo, con PID %i y voy a abrir la calculadora\n", getpid());
        calculadora(argv[1]);
    } else {
        if (pid > 0) {
            // F0: Aqui sigue ejecutando el padre luego de lanzar el fork F1
            hijos++;
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                // F2: Segundo fork
                printf("Soy el 2º hijo, con PID %i y voy a abrir n ficheros\n", getpid());
                ficheros(argv + 2);
            } else {
                // F0: En el padre.
                if (pid > 0) {
                    // F0: fork exitoso.
                    hijos++;
                } else {
                    printf("Error al crear el proceso 'ficheros'. Errno: %i\n", errno);                    
                }
            }
        } else {
            // F0: Fallo el fork.
            printf("Error al crear el proceso 'calculadora'. Errno: %i\n", errno);            
        }
    }

    // Todos los procesos siguen por aqui una vez lanzadas las aplicaciones.
    // F0: Ahora queda esperar a que los hijos terminen.
    while (pid && hijos) { // Hijos a esperar.
        pidd = wait(&status); // Aqui quedamos bloqueados hasta que
        hijos--; // alguien termine.
        // Ojo: No hay que hacer `exit` aqui adentro, pues 
        // terminariamos junto con el primer hijo terminado.
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("Hijo %i ha sido esperado y su status es %i\n", pidd, WEXITSTATUS(status));
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("Hijo %i ha muerto y su status es %i\n", pidd, WTERMSIG(status));
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            printf("Hijo %i ha sufrido un error y su status es %i\n", pidd, WSTOPSIG(status));
        }
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Comprobación**

```
candid@gear:~/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2$ dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_2 gnome-calculator xed fichero1.txt fichero2.txt
Introduce una cantidad de ficheros: 
2
Soy el 1º hijo, con PID 9830 y voy a abrir la calculadora
Soy el 2º hijo, con PID 9831 y voy a abrir n ficheros
Hijo 9831 ha sido esperado y su status es 0
Hijo 9830 ha sido esperado y su status es 0
```

**Edición**

A sugerencia de @user3629249, cambie el código de modo que no dependa de los `pid` generados. Ahora el código simplemente cuenta en `hijos` los `fork` generados con éxito para controlar la espera a que terminen.

Comment: con respecto a: ʻif (pid> 0) `Esto SÓLO comprobará la segunda llamada a` fork () `, no la primera llamada a` fork () `Probablemente no sea lo que quieres.